# How to melt and roll silver chloride into sheets

Tags: electrochemistry, home-experiment

I want to make silver chloride cathodes for a magnesium salt water battery.
Are there any tips on how to proceed?

I hope to melt the silver chloride in a covered ceramic crucible in an electric furnace, then cast a small ingot.
This ingot will be pressed and rolled into a thin sheet.
Silver chloride is nonconductive and is made conductive by superficially reducing the surface to silver by immersion in a photo-graphic developing solution.
By forming a silver outer surface that is porous, no base grid need be used with silver chloride.

Any help or direction to information is appreciated so I don't have to "reinvent the wheel".

Comment: Silver chloride is not a metal, you can't roll it.

Comment: The wikipedia article on silver chloride says it can be hot pressed into windows and lens shapes.

Comment: @EdV Jup, just like KBr (at RT even), but then you end up with a solid piece, nothing porous. I'm not clear how this battery is supposed to work.

Comment: It looks trickier than using a support grid. It should be the other way around, perhaps. I.e. silver grid / foil with some AgCl deposited onto. That can be easily done electrochemically, and if one stops the deposition while the process is ongoing, the contact to the underlying metal electrode is guaranteed. Look for quasi Ag/AgCl electrode.

Comment: @Karl Yeah, so like making a KBr pellet in a press. I also have no idea how the proposed cell would work.

Comment: There are different ideas on addressing the impermeability of the rolled AgCl sheet.  Some say you should add the AgCl to a weak solution of photographic developer for some unspecified period of time until a small portion of each AgCl particle has been turned into metallic Silver.  Then this mass is dried and pressed to form a conductive porous block. Others say that the AgCl should be formed into a sheet of the desired thickness and then the outside is reduced just enough to be conductive but still be porous enough to allow Cl- ions of the electrolyte to penetrate.  An "inside out" electrode.

Comment: @Ed V, do you have experience making KBr in a press?  If so what sort of pressure would I need to exert to form a pellet?

Comment: @Alchimista You say in your comment that it is done easily, but I am a bit clueless. How would I electrochemically deposit AgCl onto a mesh?

Comment: @user85003 silver mesh plus NaCl

Comment: The last time I made KBr pellets was long ago, using a simple lab pellet press. There are also even simpler presses that use a couple of wrenches and elbow grease. I don’t know the actual pressure because the process was done until you got a good quality pellet for the IR spectrometer. As for making Ag/AgCl electrodes, e.g., reference electrodes, that is just a matter of electrolytically oxidizing Ag in a KCl or NaCl solution. The comment by @user85003 is interesting: perhaps chat them them?

Comment: @EdV Typical IR press tools are rated to 2-10 kbar. 2kbar at 45mm dia. are of course already 30t, 400kg at 5mm dia. At some lower pressure limit one will notice that it actually takes time for the KBr to cold flow and fuse into a solid piece. ;)